# Strange behavior of NodeJS - data gets sendet but no server response (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

**Intro:**
I have started to get a little involved with NodeJS.

**What I do:**
Now I send some Data through a form (of the VUE App) to my backend (NodeJS), where the data gets written into a MongoDB (using Atlas)- everythings is working as it should (more or less) data gets written into Database.

**The problem:**
One thing is not working as thought. After I send the data, which should be executed after the respond isn't getting executed. After a while I receive an error of:

> POST http://localhost:3000/test net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

- If data gets written, I get the error and the code inside .then() wont get executed
- if I get an error (for example cz. the related path to send the data doesn't exist the code inside .catch() will get executed.

Since I am not a backend guy I don't really understand what's the issue about that. Hope somebody's able to help.

**Vue + Axios**

```
    submit() {

        if ( this.newWorkoutCollection.workoutName !== "" || null ) {

            axios.post('/workout', this.newWorkoutCollection)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
                console.log("result")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                console.log("error")
            });

        } else {
            console.log("Something else...!")
        }
    },
```

**NodeJS + Express (Controller)**

```
exports.addNewWorkout= (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    // get values
    const workoutName = req.body.workoutName;
    const workoutItems = req.body.workoutItems;

    // paste values into class
    const workout = new Workout(workoutName, workoutItems);

    workout
        .save()
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending a response in the `addNewWorkout` route callback. If you do not send a response, the request will timeout after a while(default is about 2 minutes) with an empty response.

```
workout.save()
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
});
```